# Use quantum feauture map different from ZZFeatureMap

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-kernel

I'm following [this tutorial](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/tutorials/03_quantum_kernel.html) to try and implement a QSVC on the Iris dataset. The tutorial uses [`ZZFeatureMap`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.ZZFeatureMap) to create the kernel with `FidelityQuantumKernel`, but I want to try and use different feature maps (such as the ones described in Section III in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07128v1.pdf)). However, I'm unable to implement such feature maps. I tried, for example:

`feature_map = RawFeatureVector(X_train.shape[1])`

but when I train the SVC it says

`QiskitError: 'Cannot define a ParameterizedInitialize with unbound parameters'`

How can I implement feature maps to create kernels as

`kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(fidelity=fidelity, feature_map=feature_map)`?

Answer (score 1):

`RawFeatureVector` is not built into a circuit until it's passed parameters. The `FidelityQuantumKernel` uses a Fidelity which tries to compose the `feature_map`, the `RawFeaturevector` in your example, with its `inverse()`. Since this circuit is not yet defined, this fails and leads to the above error.

Now, you can define your own feature map and pass it in a `QuantumCircuit` representing that. But the `RawFeatureVector` is more of a special case.

Comment: Any hint on how to to that? I need to implement Amplitude Encoding (that's why I was trying to use RawFeatureVector).